# Getting a .mov on the Web for All

Tags: javascript, flash, html, video-streaming, movie

I have an .mov file that is too long to upload to YouTube. I want to put it up in essentially a YouTube player but have the video be self-hosted. Can anyone recommend an easy way to do this and make it cross-browser compatible?

Comment: Is converting the file out of the question?

Comment: No, definitely willing to convert to any format which is most viewable. Any ideas on which format that is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublime Video is going to be an awesome HTML5 player someday!

A flash player is okay, flowplayer and jwplayer are usable.

Vimeo also hosts videos!

.mov just isn't that friendly for the web.

Comment: Vimeo is an awesome choice, Kirk. They have good premium features nearby too, shall you need them.

Answer (score 1):

YouTube already has a HTML5 mode (which you have to opt into though) which I assume means they convert the videos themselves. It's worth checking out, but as I mentioned, each user has to opt into using the HTML5 mode so it's probably not worth it.

If you're going to host it yourself, I'd suggest converting it to OGG and MP4 (and possibly WEBM) and playing it through the [MediaElementJS](http://mediaelementjs.com) player.